# FB.ui() ignoring the "to" property

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

Has anyone experienced the situation where the "to" property of FB.ui gets ignored - even if it's set - and the post *only* goes to the wall of the currently logged in user?

When working with a completely stripped down test page that uses the FB sample code (and hard-coded parameter values) it posts to my wall as expected. But when I add "to" property to this FB code, it *still* only posts to my wall.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, as I have trawled these archives and the FB dev site in what I believe to be a thorough way.

The SDK loads properly and the iframe pops up (though it scrolls to the top of the page).

Here's the stripped down code used in my test page:

```
$("#well").click(function(e) {
  FB.ui(
  {
   method: 'feed',
   to: '***', /* <=== this person is a confirmed friend with appropriate privacy settings */
   name: 'The Facebook SDK for Javascript',
   caption: 'Bringing Facebook to the desktop and mobile web',
   description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
   ),
   link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/',
   picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/public/f8.jpg'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

Thanks in advance.

## # # UPDATE # #

Thanks to Sahil Mittal's contributions I worked out this fairly reasonable solution:

`

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "http://graph.facebook.com/"+$("#fbto").val()+"?fields=id", function( data ) {
 // could do something useful here... 
})

.done(function(  data ) {
  // do something else useful useful, in this case finish posting stuff to the wall 
})

.fail(function(  data ) {
 // thrown if the user doesn't exist
})

.always(function(  data ) {
  // etc... 
})
```

`

Now, this is a jQuery 1.8.* solution, and I should also add that in a high-traffic scenario I'm not sure how kindly FB would take to hammering on their URL to convert submitted usernames to ids. But that's a bridge I'll happily cross if we get there!

Thanks again to Sahil.

Comment: You must be using invalid `to` parameter. Can you show?

Comment: by this do you mean the exact FB user ID?

Comment: Yes. Or check if its correct

Comment: I'd rather not share the id in public, but it is a valid FB user page. If i share the item *from* my wall (posted via the code above) to this test user it works. I would expect an error to be thrown by FB if the user is not valid, correct?

Comment: You're not getting my point. What exactly are you giving in the `to` parameter? What's the format?

Comment: Ah! ok. a text string. e.g. `to: 'fbusername',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `username` in the `to` parameter. You have to use **`id`** instead.

If you dont have the id, you can get that from the username itself. Make the call `/{username}?fields=id` and you'll get the id in response.

For eg: http://graph.facebook.com/sahilmittal?fields=id.

The response is:

```
{
  id: "595273610"
}
```

Just get this `id` and use it in the **`to`** parameter.

Comment: VERY USEFUL ANSWER!!! But what if I'm getting the username from the site visitor via a form? Am I going to have to write some kind of routine to convert their NAME to the ID?

Comment: Didn't got you- `I'm getting the username from the site visitor via a form`

Comment: Also, pls click on the right tick if that worked for you to close the discussion

Comment: Thanks for all your help. However, this contradicts the FB documentation: [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog] **The ID or username of the profile that this story will be published to. If this is unspecified, it defaults to the value of from.**

This means it should work with a username.

Comment: Thanks! I really do appreciate your effort. It's FB that's making me mad. Will vote your contributions up as they are definitely a solution.

Comment: You can subscribe to this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/456622171135665/. They'll update the docs.